# I am getting a wrong output for my battleship program

Tags: loops, kotlin

I am creating a battleship program and when I implement this code:

```
import java.util.Scanner

fun main() {
    var battleship: MutableList<MutableList<Any>> = mutableListOf(mutableListOf(0, 1, 2, 3, 4),
            mutableListOf(0, 1, 2, 3, 4), mutableListOf(0, 1, 2, 3, 4),
            mutableListOf(0, 1, 2, 3, 4), mutableListOf(0, 1, 2, 3, 4))
    val scan = Scanner(System.`in`)
    var userInput: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()
    var fill: MutableList<Int> = mutableListOf()
    var rowCounter:MutableList<Any> = mutableListOf("", "", "", "", "")
    var columnCounter:MutableList<Any> = mutableListOf("", "", "", "", "")
    var counter = 0
    while (scan.hasNext()) {
        userInput.add(scan.next())
    }

    for (each in userInput) {
        if (userInput.indexOf(each) % 2 != 0) {
            fill.add(each.toInt() - 1)
        } else if (userInput.indexOf(each) % 2 == 0) {
            fill.add(each.toInt() - 1)
        }
        if (fill.size == 2) {
            battleship[(fill[0])].add(fill[1], "X")
            battleship[(fill[0])].removeAt((fill[1] + 1))
            fill.clear()
            continue
        }
    }

    for (each in battleship) {
        if ("X" in each) {
            rowCounter.add(battleship.indexOf(each), battleship.indexOf(each) + 1)
            rowCounter.removeAt(battleship.indexOf(each) + 1)
        }
        for (element in each) {
            if ("X" == element) {
                columnCounter.add(each.indexOf(element), each.indexOf(element) + 1)
                columnCounter.removeAt(each.indexOf(element) + 1)
            }
        }
    }

    for (each in 0..4) {
        counter++
        if (rowCounter[each] == "" && counter != 5) {
            print(counter.toString() + " ")
        } else if (rowCounter[each] == ""){
            print(counter.toString())
        }
    }
    counter = 0
    println()

    for (each in 0..4) {
        counter++
        if (columnCounter[each] == "" && counter != 5) {
            print(counter.toString() + " ")
        } else if (columnCounter[each] == ""){
            print(counter.toString())
        }
    }
}
```

I am given an output of
**2 3 4 5\n1 3 4 5** when it should be **2 3 4 5\n1 5**

The first row indicates the rows which are empty after user input and the second row indicates the columns that are empty after user input. User input for this round is: **1 3\n1 4\n1 2** where the first number is the row and the second number is the column in each line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Analysis of what went wrong

When counting rows, you remove the element at the index of `"X"` in the current row. Looking at the documentation of [`indexOf()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/index-of.html), what happens when we are processing the second `"X"` in the row `0 "X" "X" "X" 4`?

> Returns the index of the first occurrence of the specified element in the list.

Right. This returns the index of the **first** `"X"`, and thus it will remove the row number from your `columnCount` list (instead of the next empty string you intended to remove).

## How to find empty rows and columns

If you are only interested in which rows and columns are empty, you can do something like the following.

First, convert the input to `Int`s because that is easier to work with, and split them into `Pair`s. <sup>1</sup>

```kotlin
val userInputPairs: List<Pair<Int>> = userInput
    .map { it.toInt() }
    .chunked(2) { input -> Pair(input[0], input[1])}
```

Now you can count all rows (and columns) that have been hit (using [`distinct()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/distinct.html)) and look at the set difference.

```kotlin
val hitRows = userInputPairs.map { it.first }.distinct().toSet()
val emptyRows = (1..5).toSet() - hitRows
```

You could combine this into one line, but it is up to you if that is easier to read or not.

```kotlin
val emptyColumns = (1..5).toSet() - userInputPairs.map { it.last }.distinct().toSet()
```

## Some general remarks

While looking at your code I found a few things that I wanted to point out to you, and give you a few tips. This is no criticism, I just thought you (and maybe others who are just starting out) might benefit.

1. Try to avoid to use `Any` in your types. Using `Any` as a type makes your program a lot harder to reason about and to debug. It also makes it easier to introduce bugs (which are then harder to find) since there is no type checking really.
2. Formatting a string can be done with [string templates](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/basic-syntax.html#string-templates). So, e.g., you can use `"$counter "` instead of `counter.toString() + " "`.
3. Use the [inspections](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/code-inspection.html) provided by IntelliJ (the yellow squiggly lines underneath code). They can teach you some code style, find bugs, or inform you about other ways to write things down (the string templates is one of the inspections).
4. When writing a program like this, it can often be beneficial to come up with a model to represent your program. This will take some practice, but it will make it easier to read and reason about your program. Small programs like the one at hand here are perfect to practice this! Try to come up with a few different representations and just play around with them to see what is easier, more readable, or suits your current use-case best.

---

<sup>1</sup> In your final code you're probably better of by implementing a custom `Cell` class so you can name the properties `row` and `column` instead of `first` and `last` to avoid confusion.